# How can I close a CMD window using javascript?

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, activex

I am writing a page once save to a local computer it can run *cmd* do a *tracert*, *ping* and other things for networking diagnostics only the page works for the most page but I can't figure out how to close the cmd window after it saves the results to a file?

And it only work in IE.

> Runs *tracert* > saves to file > file is pulled to textarea > sent via
>   email

I want system to put this in popup.
**I've tried:**

```
WshShell.close()
WshShell.Quit
WScript.close
WScript.Quit

<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
    function RunFile3() {
    var domain = document.getElementById("domain").value;
    WshShell = new ActiveXObject("WScript.Shell");
    WshShell.Run("c:/windows/system32/cmd.exe /k tracert " + domain + " > C:/xampp/htdocs/tracert/trace.txt", 1, false);
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<input type="text" id="domain">
!---<input type="button" value="Run Ping" onclick="RunFile2();"/>--->
<input type="button" value="Run Tracert" onclick="RunFile3();"/>
<br>
<textarea rows="30" cols="60" id="results">
</textarea>
```

Comment: Your question is not clear, please rephrase your question.

Comment: im writing the page in java script once the cmd runs to get the tracert it stays open i need a way to close the window in the same process

Answer (score 1):

You could trace the command window by WMI, and then terminate the process. Like so:

```
function closeCMD () {
    var wmiLocator = new ActiveXObject('WbemScripting.SWbemLocator'),
        wmiService = wmiLocator.ConnectServer('.', 'root\\CIMV2'),
        cmdWindows = new Enumerator(wmiService.ExecQuery("Select * from Win32_Process Where name = 'cmd.exe'"));
    while (!cmdWindows.atEnd()) {
        if (cmdWindows.item().CommandLine.indexOf('trace.txt') > -1) { // *
            cmdWindows.item().Terminate(0);
        }
        cmdWindows.moveNext();
    }
    return;
}
```

* = `trace.txt`, or whatever content of the original commandline call (the parameter part of the string which is passed to cmd.exe in the first argument passed to `Run`) which uniquely identifies the specific cmd window you want to close.

If you want to close all the cmd windows, you can remove the condition from the loop, and just do `cmdWindows.item().Terminate(0);`.

**Important!**
Before calling the function, you've to set the cmd call synchronous, so that you won't close the window before it has done its job. That can be achieved by changing the third argument of `Run` to `true` (i.e. the argument you currently pass as `false`).

---

You can also easily change the function more generic, just pass the process name and the identifier as arguments, and build the WMI query string with the process argument and pass the indentifier argument to `indexOf`.